# Check if string is not a number before converting it to a int

Tags: c++

I have got a terminal app that gets user input stores it in a string then converts it into a int. The problem is if the user inputs anything that is not a number the conversion fails and the script continues without any indication that the string has not converted. Is there a way to check of the string contains any non digit characters.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string mystr;
  float price=0;
  int quantity=0;

  cout << "Enter price: ";
  getline (cin,mystr); //gets user input
  stringstream(mystr) >> price;  //converts string: mystr to float: price
  cout << "Enter quantity: ";
  getline (cin,mystr); //gets user input
  stringstream(mystr) >> quantity; //converts string: mystr to int: quantity
  cout << "Total price: " << price*quantity << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Just before the conversion here: `stringstream(mystr) >> price;` I want it to print a line to the console if the string is Not a Number.

Comment: `if(!(stringstream(mystr) >> quantity)) cout << "Not a number" << std::endl;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out if a read of an `int` has been successful or not by checking the `fail()` bit of your input stream:

```
getline (cin,mystr); //gets user input
stringstream priceStream(mystr);
priceStream >> price;
if (priceStream.fail()) {
    cerr << "The price you have entered is not a valid number." << endl;
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/Qh2qVr)

Comment: You also use bad(), what's the difference?

Comment: @herohuyongtao It's an error I made while typing up the demo, which is now fixed: it should have been `fail()` in both places.

Answer (score 0):

If your want to check if the price user inputs is a float, you can use `boost::lexical_cast<double>(mystr);`, if it throws an exception then your string is not a float.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to add a bit to your code, but you can parse mystr with isdigit from cctype. The library's functions are [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/). isdigit(mystr[index]) will return a false if that character in the string isn't a number.